# Dynamically Filter data in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, .net-2.0, asp.net-3.5

I have a ComboBox with the values "open", "closed". According to values changed in the ComboBox, I want to change the DataGrid to display either "open " or "closed" values. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.aspx) can be bound to a [DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx). Create different *DataViews* depending upon the Selected item in the [DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx) (here's an article on [how to retrieve the selected item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5kfekd2(VS.80).aspx)).

Fill a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) with your data. [Derive different DataViews for the combo states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8sd1cd0a.aspx). When the combo changes (enable AutoPostback), select the appropriate DataView and [Bind the DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kf1c24y6.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [RowFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx) property of a DataView object binded to the DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the *DataSource controls and add a control parameter with the ID of the combobox. Turn on autopostback for the combo, and asp.net will automatically call the object datasource with the new open/closed value.